# Meaning of method side effects in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, side-effects

Martin Odersky's book 'Programming in Scala' speaks about avoiding methods which have side effects.
Like, following method has side effect of writing to standard output stream.

```
def printArgs(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  args.foreach(println)
}
```

It then says, better way would be to define a method that formats
the passed args for printing, but just returns the formatted string,like:

```
def formatArgs(args: Array[String]) = args.mkString("\n")
```

I don't understand how are these two approaches different conceptually.Afterall, our aim here is to print a string.If we don't do it in target method, then client code would do it, meaning we are just shifting the code causing 'side effects' from one place to another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are different, because the side-effects are clearly contained in a small number of methods at the very edge of the system.

Side-effects destroy *many* desirable properties, such as composability, testability, maintainability, reusability, local reasoning, referential transparency, purity, equational reasoning, and many others. So, you *want* them to be contained into as small a piece of code as possible.

To give you just one example, regarding composability. What if, in addition to printing the arguments to the console, you also want to write them to a logfile? Note that the two are actually *the exact same thing*, you are just writing to an IO stream, one of which happens to be connected to a file and one of which happens to be connected to the standard output of your terminal.

And yet, you cannot re-use the logic, you have to duplicate it, because the logic for generation of the string is intermingled with the logic for printing it. Whereas in the second solution, if you have a method for, say,  logging a string to a database, then you can simply compose that method with your method for generating a string from the arguments to have a method to log your arguments to a database.

Another example regarding testability: testing methods that print to the terminal is a real pain. You have to somehow capture the output from the terminal.

Testing a method that returns a string is trivial, you just compare the return value with an expected value. And you don't actually *have* to test the printing to the terminal, because that's a method that is provided by the Scala standard library which has already been extensively tested (and if it were broken, you'd have much bigger problems anyway).

Note that in the first solution, you are *forced* to do the duplicate work of testing whether `println` works, there is no way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically our aim as a programmer must be to make our methods as concise as possible,ie make methods do very specific tasks, rather than making them handle several concerns.

Comment: Yes, that is the *general* idea, make each method do *one thing* and do it *well*. *Specifically*, you should isolate side-effects into small and trivial methods at the boundaries of your system. Side-effects are hard to test, so methods that have side-effects should be *so trivial* that just by looking at them, you can see that they are *obviously* correct. In general, it is a good idea to separate: input, generation, transformation, consumption, output of data.

Comment: C.A.R. Hoare said "There are two ways of constructing a software design.  The first is to make it so simple there are obviously no deficiencies.  The second is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies.  The first is much more difficult."  Removing side effects moves you toward that first solution.